# How to reset mysql modes to default after doing SET sql_mode = ''

Tags: mysql, homestead

I accidentally did `SET sql_mode = ''` while trying to disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` which resets all modes currently enabled. How can I revert to the default settings? I'm running `MySQL 5.7.20` on a Homestead Vagrant box.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The query

```
 SET sql_mode = '';
```

only works on the current connection. 
So you can disconnect and reconnect your client and your default sql_mode should be restored.

To disable 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY' without disabling other sql_mode can be done like this.

```
  SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT(REPLACE(@@sql_mode, ',ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', ''));
```

**p.s**
Keep in mind that `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is enabled with a reason in the modern MySQL versions, i don't advice to disable it.

Comment: I ran `SELECT @@sql_mode;` before and after disconnecting and it it was indeed just for the current connection. Disabling `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` the way you suggested also worked. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

It's all walking around, because it may change from version to vesrion. To reset it you should use standard practice:

```
set global sql_mode=default
set session sql_mode=default
```

After that you can check it by:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode
```

Answer (score 1):

for default  inn 5.7 you should set

```
sql_mode = "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, 
      NO_ZERO_DATE, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO, NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,
      NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html

check for your real mysql version and subversion for other param